# Turning percentages into decimals?

Tags: sed, perl

I've got a CSV file that has percentages here and there expressed in text format, e.g.

```
173.91,0.00%,36.10%,1.71
```

Question of the day is how do I turn that example into

```
173.91,0,0.3610,1.71
```

Edit to add:  You should not rely on the position of the percentage fields. You should detect them based on the % sign.

Comment: Do any fields contain text strings with embedded newlines?

Comment: Please add more examples of what you want the script to contend with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '173.91,0.00%,36.10%,1.71'|perl -pe 's{\d+\.\d+%}{$&/100}eg'
173.91,0,0.361,1.71
```

The regex looks for a float with % and in the last curly brackets evaluates the expression: matching string `$&` divided by 100.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` example:

```
$ awk -F, '{sub(/%/,"",$2); sub(/%/,"",$3); \
      printf("%.2f,%.0f,%.4f,%.2f\n"), $1, $2, $3/100, $4}' ex.txt 
173.91,0,0.3610,1.71
```

#### Details

1. We tell `awk` to split the contents of file `ex.txt` using commas, `-F,`.
2. `sub(/%/,"",$2)` & `sub(/%/,"",$3)` strip the percent signs off.
3. `printf("%.2f,%.0f,%.4f,%.2f\n")` takes care to format everything.
4. The parameters to `printf`, `$1`, `$2`, `$4` are just the contents of the file, the 3rd one, `$3/100` we divide by 100 to get it in decimal form.

#### Improving the design

One thing we can immediately improve, assuming we don't care about percent signs, is to completely remove them using `gsub` to globally substitute them out.

```
$ awk -F, '{sub(/%/,"",$0); \
      printf("%.2f,%.0f,%.4f,%.2f\n"), $1, $2, $3/100, $4}' ex.txt 
173.91,0,0.3610,1.71
```